# MySQL query that SHOULDN'T return anything, returns with a record

Tags: mysql

So I'm writing a query to pull records. It goes:

```
SELECT dossier.*
FROM dossier
WHERE dossier.id = '097a520ef2be66c53506cb0f3552557e'
LIMIT 1
```

My `id` field is `INT`. There is a record with the `id` of 97, but **not** `097a520ef2be66c53506cb0f3552557e`, so I should not get any records back.

But I just get records back: https://prnt.sc/otn1uz

Any ideas on how to properly query that field, and what would cause MySQL to incorrectly think
97 = 097a520ef2be66c53506cb0f3552557e?

Comment: What happens is implicit conversion of `'097a520ef2be66c53506cb0f3552557e'` to integer and since the starting part of it is `097` it is converted to `97`.

Comment: See this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: god, that's evil. had to detect the MD5 hash and build it into two queries to avoid that conversion. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Why are you comparing an INT to a string in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, when you compare a string with an integer, MySQL automatically converts the string to an integer first. If the string contains a numeric prefix, it's converted to that number, otherwise it becomes `0`.

One way to avoid this is to cast the integer to a string before comparing:

```
WHERE CAST(dossier.id AS CHAR) = '097a520ef2be66c53506cb0f3552557e'
```

Another solution is to use `LIKE` rather than `=`. Since this is a string operation, it will automatically convert the number to a string first.

```
WHERE dossier.id LIKE '097a520ef2be66c53506cb0f3552557e'
```

`LIKE` is normally less efficient than `=` because it performs a pattern match, but I assume that MySQL will optimize this into an quality test when there are no wildcards in the pattern.

However, neither of these will be able to take advantage of an index on the ID field. The best solution would be to avoid comparing an `INT` column to an arbitrary string in the first place.

Comment: It's not at all clear why this answer is downvoted. MySQL is doing an implicit conversion of a string literal into INT, and getting value of 97. This behavior is explicitly documented in the MySQL Reference Manual. As far as the question that was asked, "how to properly query this field", big rock is to change the SQL query to *avoid* comparing an INT column to a string. To avoid the conversion of the string to INT, both methods outlined in this answer are workable, albeit not the most desirable in terms of performance. +10.